# Как вставить пример кода в php html страницу?

Tags: php

На странице primer.php нужно разместить код типа

Вставьте это между тегами HEAD на своей странице:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Тело ЯваСкрипта </script>
```

А вслед за этим в любую область сайта:

```
<div id="content"><img src="loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

И нужно, чтобы пользователи сайта видели это... В общем, как на этом форуме. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Подсветка кода PHP, HTML, JS, CSS, SQL (MySQL), shell](http://anton-pribora.ru/site/hl.php).

А на PHP исходник выводится так:

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>'.highlight_string($source, TRUE).'</pre>';
?>
```

Где $source - это исходник php-скрипта, полученный, например, с помощью file_get_contents().